# string returning null on append

Tags: java

I've been tasked to create a word guessing game. You only have 5 tries to guess the word. User enters in one letter at a time to try to figure out my secret word which is "juice" but you're supposed to work with a hint word construct which each guess replaces the asterisks with the correct letter if it is correct.

**This is what the output is supposed to look like:**

> Welcome to the word guessing game! You have 5 tries to guess the secret word!
>   The current hint is
>
> ---
>
> Guess a lowercase letter
>
> u
>
> *u***
>
> Guess the secret word
>
> tutre
>
> Keep trying!
>
> Guess a lowercase letter
>
> t
>
> *u***
>
> Guess the secret word
>
> mutor
>
> Keep trying!

... Continues on till 5 tries then you either win or lose

**My output does not keep letting you try to guess and the hint word is obviously messed up since it has the null infront of the 5 asterisks.. I'm not sure how to fix it.**

> The current hint is
>
> null*****
>
> Guess a lowercase letter
>
> j
>
> jull*
>
> Guess the secret word
>
> jutre
>
> Keep trying!
>
> Game over! Try again?

**Here's my class:**

```
public class SecretWord {
private String secretWord;
private String hintWord;
private int numberOfTurns;

//Default Constructors
public SecretWord()
{
    this.secretWord = "juice";
    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
    {
        this.hintWord+="*";
    }
    this.numberOfTurns = 0;
}
//Accessors
public String getSecretWord()
{
    return this.secretWord;
}
public String getHintWord()
{
    return this.hintWord;
}
public int getNumberOfTurns()
{
    return this.numberOfTurns;
}
//Mutators
public void setSecretWord ()
{
    this.secretWord = "juice";
}
public void setHintWord ()
{
    char[] correctLetters = new char[secretWord.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i<secretWord.length();i++)
    {
        hintWord+="*";
        correctLetters[i] += '*';
    }
}
public void setNumberOfTurns (int i)
{
    this.numberOfTurns = 5;
}
//Methods
public void guessLetter(char guess)
{
    String tempHintWord="";
    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
    {
        if (secretWord.charAt(i) == guess)
        {
            tempHintWord += guess;
        }
        else
        {
            tempHintWord += hintWord.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    hintWord = tempHintWord;
}
```

**Here's my driver class:**

```
public class SecretWordGame {

//Constant for number of tries
public static final int NUM_TRIES = 5;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Starts game
    boolean quit = false;
    while (quit == false)

    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the word guessing game! You have " +
                +NUM_TRIES+" tries to guess the secret word!");

                SecretWord myWord = new SecretWord();
        System.out.println("The current hint is \n"+myWord.getHintWord());

        while (myWord.getNumberOfTurns() <NUM_TRIES)
        {
            System.out.println("Guess a lowercase letter");

            //Gets the first letter of what is entered

            char guess = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

            //Updates the hint by calling guess letter method

            myWord.guessLetter(guess);

            System.out.println(myWord.getHintWord());

            System.out.println("Guess the secret word");

            String myGuess = keyboard.nextLine();
            //Checks correct guess
            if (myGuess.equals(myWord.getSecretWord()))
            {
                System.out.println("You win!");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Keep trying!");
            }

            myWord.setNumberOfTurns(myWord.getNumberOfTurns()+1);
        }
        //Prompts user to play again

        System.out.println("Game over! Try again?");

        String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            quit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Let's go again!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

Comment: You should set hintWord before using it in the constructur. Setting it to "" should work.

Comment: The hintWord is not `null` its `"null*****"` as you might expect from the code. If you are wondering why, place a break point on the setHintWord() method and step through the code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Do you know why it's not stopping at 5 letter guesses like it's supposed to?

Comment: You are always setting `this.numberOfTurns = 5;` and you ignore the value passed in. Again this is something you can see in a debugger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SecretWord`'s `hintword` is initialized to `null` by default. So when you append to it `+= "*"` it converts the current value to `"null"` and then adds the `"*"`. If you initialize hintword where you declare it to `""` it will fix that issue.

Comment: do you know why it's not stopping after 5 letter guesses like it's supposed to?

Comment: setNumberOfTurns ignores its parameter <code>i<code> and instead always sets the value of the variable to 5. It's called at the end of the while loop. This causes the next check of the while's condition to return false and the loop is exited.

Answer (score 1):

In `SecretWord` class you do not initialize `hintWord`.
Therefore, when performing `hintWord += "*";`, hintWord is `null`, which then implicitly turned into the string `"null"` to concatenate with `"*"`.*

Comment: Do you know why it's not stopping after 5 letter guesses like it's supposed to?

Comment: @ChrisM well, `setNumberOfTurns (int i)</code> doesn't set `numberOfTurns` to `i`, and also `NUM_TRIES` is declared final. So neither one ever changes value.